# Create a repetitive loop so the program will ask the user if another entry is desired until the user indicates “No.”

Tags: java, while-loop

This is what the assignment requires:
I need to create a Java program to accept input for the following two variables: (a) Students and (b) Scores.
I need to also create a repetitive loop so the program will ask the user if another entry is desired until the user indicates “No.”
I need to include a variable that will compute the average score for an entire class.
I need to create a variable that will assign a letter grade based on the student’s score using a chart (A=.93,A-=.90 B=.87, etc.)
I must Create a variable that will list the number of students who received each of the following grade ranges: A, B, C, D, and F. (Note that “+” and “-” grades fall within the general letter grade range.)

I was able to piece some part of the code but I can't put it together. This is my first class and there is no real instruction or direction as to how to proceed. The following are the pieces of code I am attempting to integrate.

```
package gradeproject;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
public class ComputeGradeTryCatch {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // This is the first piece of the code.

            int score1;
    Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Student Name: ");
    String name = s.next();

    boolean done = false;
    while (!done) {

    System.out.println("Enter one test score: ");
    try
    {
    score1 = s.nextInt();
    done = true;

    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e){
    System.out.println("Enter a Numeric Value");
    }
    s.nextLine();


            //This is a second piece of the code

Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Student Name: ");
    String name = s.next();
    System.out.println("Enter three test scores: ");
    int score1 = s.nextInt();
    int score2 = s.nextInt();
    int score3 = s.nextInt();
char letterGrade;
    double average = (score1 + score2 +score3)/3;
    System.out.println("Name: " + name);
    System.out.println("Scores are: " + score1 + "" + score2 + "" +            score3);
    System.out.println("Average: " + average);
if ((average >=90  && average <=100 ))
letterGrade = 'A';
else if ((average >=80  && average <=90 ))
letterGrade = 'B';
else if ((average >=70  && average <=80 ))
letterGrade = 'C';
else if ((average >=60  && average <=70 ))
letterGrade = 'D';
else letterGrade = 'F';

    System.out.println(" Letter Grade is : " + letterGrade);

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
\\\\This is the third piece of the code

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
static String userInput = null;
{
    checkPrime();
    while (true)
    {
        System.out.print("Do You Want to Continue (Y/N) ?");


        if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
            checkPrime();
        else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
        {
        System.out.print("Thank you !!");
            break;
        }
        else{
        System.out.print("Try Again With (Y/N) only !");   
        }

\\This has been a rather challenging task. Thank you for your help             and support!

There are errors in all of the three parts of the code when I run    it. My goal is to put together a clean piece of code that will execute the desire outcome in a concise manner.
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using functions properly.

Both times you write checkPrime(), you're just calling a function called checkPrime(), which I think doesn't exists (or atleast you didn't provide the code of that function).

You should do something like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
    do {
        print("What do you want to do? a) Add a new student with one score b) Add a student with three scores");
        String input = s.next()
        if (input.equals("a")) {
            // Do your A stuff
        } else if (input.equals("b")) {
            // Do your B stuff
        }
        print("Do you want to continue? (Y/N)");
        input = s.next()
    } while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
}
```

Keep in mind that the previous code isn't finished, and is just meant to give you some guidelines to understand what you should do.

Comment: Thanks Roberto I will try to put this together.

Comment: Good luck! Feel free to ask more doubts that may arise.